# NestJs: erro com provider não importado

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, microsserviços

sou iniciante utilizando o framework NestJs, e me deparei com o seguinte erro ao compilar meu codigo... :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, estou desenvolvendo um micro serviço que recebe uma solicitação get, e consulta a lib cep-promise, retornando informações sobre o endereço referenciado ao cep.
essa é minha classe de serviço:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe consegue me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?
Obrigado a todos!!!

Comment: Consegui resolver corrigindo as injeções na camada de serviço.
Encontrei lendo a documentação.

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro geralmente ocorre quando alguma dependência de uso como services de outros modulos, ou repositories não estão sendo chamados no module que os usa, você poderia postar o seu CacheCepModule?

Comment: Já que a sua resposta não resolve o problema, ela deve ser postada como comentário :)